# Perl postfix 'use'?

Tags: perl, syntax, module

I've just encountered this syntax:

```
BEGIN { IPC::Shareable->use };
```

why?
its part of a module which I contributed to, a snippet:

```
package A;
use A;
use IPC::Shareable;
use base 'C';
```

the author changed it to:

```
package A;
use A;
BEGIN { IPC::Shareable->use };
use base 'C';
```

tried asking him, but yet to get a response. my questions are:

1. why using begin in this case? isnt a `use` statement is similar to:

   BEGIN {
     require IPC::Shareable;
     IPC::Shareable->import();
   }
2. why the `IPC::Shareable->use` instead `use IPC::Shareable;` ?

Comment: [`B`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B.html) is actually a core library to the Perl Compiler Backend.  I assume your references to A, B, and C are meant to be placeholders?  Perhaps show the actual code instead of a placeholder?

Comment: A,B,C are just examples, I'm not referring to the core modules here (-:   The real code are just long in house module names...

Comment: Calling `use` as a method is not a Perl facility.  Presumably (and very confusingly), `B` supplies a `use` method.  This is likely not something that can be answered without reference to the source code you are working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, [UNIVERSAL::require](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL::require) has been loaded at some point. This module allows `use` to be called as a method.

UNIVERSAL::require used to have some fairly worrying bugs, but as of 0.17 should be mostly OK. However, I trust [Module::Runtime](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Runtime) somewhat more than UNIVERSAL::require.

Why did the author make this change? There could be several reasons, but the most likely seems to be the fact that the `use` method provided by UNIVERSAL::require doesn't die if the module is unavailable.